# ConstraintLayout designer rendering exception

Tags: java, exception, rendering, designer, android-constraintlayout

After ConstraintLayout upgrade to alpha9 I'm getting `onMeasure()` error rendering problems in design mode:
[image: rendering problem]

Details (exception):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.immediateConnect(Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintAnchor$Type;Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintWidget;Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintAnchor$Type;II)V
>       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:555)
>       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:468)
>       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure_Original(ConstraintLayout.java:770)
>       at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:545)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:342)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If I change back dependency in build.gradle from `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9` to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8` everything is ok again.

Any tips? alpha9 version broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the release notes, depending on your platform you might have to restart studio and/or invalidate caches after installing alpha 9 :-/

Answer (score 1):

File -> Invalidate cache/restart. This will solve the problem.